# Global variables are undefined within function scope

Tags: javascript

I've got this bit of code where the variables latitude and longitude are declared outside of and then defined inside of the positionSuccess function. I would like to re-use these variables later on, but they keep returning as undefined. Not sure why.

I thought if they are defined outside of a function then they should be available within that same scope to other functions. Am I missing something here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError);

  // Gets the user's location

  var latitude;
  var longitude;

  function positionSuccess(position){
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  }

  function positionError(error){
    console.warn('ERROR: ' + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
  }

  // Other functions that need access to latitude and longitude variables.

)};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The code seems correct - verify that positonSuccess gets called beforehand.

Comment: @ConnorPeet - `positionSuccess` is async and thus is called later after the `$(document).ready()` callback function has finished executing.  That is what is causing the problem - see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to asynchronous programming in Javascript.  Because code is not executed sequentially from top to bottom in your function, asynchronous callbacks require a different method of writing code where results they receive must be processed inside the callbacks, not outside the callbacks.

`positionSuccess` and `positionError` are asynchronous callbacks.  They are called long AFTER your `$(document).ready()` handler is DONE executing.  As such, the `latitude` and `longitude` variables are not yet set when you are trying to use them.

Any code that needs the results inside of `positionSuccess()` must be placed inside that callback function or you can call some other function and pass the result variable sto it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError);

  function positionSuccess(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    // insert code to use the latitude and longitude variables here
  }

  function positionError(error){
    console.warn('ERROR: ' + error.code + ': ' + error.message);
  }

  // the latitude and longitude data is not yet available here because 
  // positionSuccess() is called in the future AFTER this part of 
  // the code executes

)};
```

Comment: Wow, awesome answer - it definitely clears it up for me. Thanks so much!